# AWS EKS aws-load-balancer-controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

i am trying to install my ca certificates with in ingress controller. I am following this guide. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html

I could run cert-manager in Node group while running other pods in fargate. I want to know

I am getting the error that says x509 error
certificate is valid for *.corp not aws-load-balancer-webhook-service.kube-system.svc

Do i need to install cert manager though i have my own tls certs. how to route traffic with tls certs from aws-load-balancer-controller.

Thanks,
Surya.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need cert manager to use certs with load balancers. Cert manager is a utility to dynamically generate  & manage the lifecycle of the certificate.

If you have your own certificate you can import those into your alb or nlb  created by load balancer controller for ingress or service objects respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can import your certs into acm service and create acm cert.

Configure the load balancer controller or ingress with acm arn to route traffic with tls.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).